# Is there a way to make MS SQL Server visible and accessible by a single application?

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions, authorization, database-permissions

I have 4 MS SQL Server databases that are accessed by 2 different applications on 2 different computers. The applications work with MS SQL Server as the host of the databases. How do l ensure that when the system is installed, the clients cannot see or manipulate my databases through another application such as SQL Server Management Studio?

I have tried the following

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<database> to <anylogin>

USE MASTER

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <anylogin>
```

to make the database accessible to only a single user. It does something but what l want is to make the databases visible and accessible by only a certain single login regardless of whichever privileges they may have. The databases should not be accessible by or visible to any other logins except for only the one that l would have dedicated to be able to do so.

Comment: A non sysadmin doesn't have any rights to access any databases you don't give it access to. You don't need a `DENY`

Comment: disable windows logins and don't give out the sql login

Comment: I think that's what might work best. Disabling windows authentications and only having one sql login. But then will that work without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a sql login with password difficult(encrypt password in connection string)
2. limited permision sql login( only user has grant Select,insert,update,delete )
3. if user is user appliction that never  has other permisions
   (alter,admin,monitroring ,....)

4.limit network access to this server(port sql )

5. disable extra user in this instance

you can be used to change ownership in SQL Server and other users can't see this database but It causes the change database's owner

i don't advice this code

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<database> to <anylogin>

USE MASTER

DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <anylogin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-ver16)